# Adding new field and calculating in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, plugins

I'm trying to write a script using QGIS 3.4. What I want to achieve is an Excel-style calculation where I can create a new field `"field2"` and calculate the difference between a current and previous row of an existing field `"field1"`.

However, I'm stuck at the first step which is creating the new field. Attached my sample code below. The first part is how I generated my layer from an interpolation process.

```
    # Interpolate
        mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs="+vlayer.sourceCrs().authid(), 'point', 'memory')
        mem_layer.startEditing()
        fields = [field for field in csvlayer.fields()]
        prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()
        prov.addAttributes(fields)
        mem_layer.updateFields()

        chainageIdx = csvlayer.fields().indexFromName(chainage_field)

        for line in vlayer.getFeatures():
            for feat in csvlayer.getFeatures():
                new_feat = QgsFeature()
                attrs = feat.attributes()
                new_feat.setGeometry(line.geometry().interpolate(float(attrs[chainageIdx])))
                new_feat.setAttributes(attrs)
                mem_layer.addFeatures([new_feat])
        mem_layer.commitChanges()

    # Calc 1
        mem_layer.startEditing()
        datetimeField = QgsField('DateTime', QVariant.Double)
        prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()
        prov.addAttributes([datetimeField])
        mem_layer.updateFields()
        fields.append(datetimeField)

        newdatetimeIdx = mem_layer.fields().indexFromName('DateTime')

        for feat in mem_layer.getFeatures():
            #mem_layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),newdatetimeIdx, 1)
            feat.setAttribute(newdatetimeIdx, 1.0)
            mem_layer.updateFeature(feat)
        mem_layer.commitChanges()

    # Output
        (sink_points, dest_id_points) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPOINTS,
            context,
            fields,
            QgsWkbTypes.Point,
            vlayer.sourceCrs()
        )
        features = mem_layer.getFeatures()
        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
            # Add a feature in the sink
            sink_points.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))
```

When I try to run this, I get a `KeyError: '2'` message which suggests that the field was not created hence it couldn't write the test value.

Comment: I'm not sure, if i understand what you want so let me do some remarks to your questions Frist you say you want to write a plugin but your code looks like a processing script. Second: in relational datasets as vector layers are you shouldn't depend of the order of rows, but use id's to connect things. Third: You use a nested for loop to create new features: are you aware that yout output will contain an amount of features equal to the multiplication of the counts of both layers? At least: where in your code does the KeyError raise? Please post the traceback of that error.

Comment: Hi @AndreasMüller, sorry my bad, I meant processing script. I will update my question to change that. The nested for loop in the Interpolate section was intentional because the input can be multiple lines, and I want to create points along those lines.

Comment: The part where I create the geometry works fine. I'm just having difficulty creating new fields to add to the created layer. The error occurs on this line `feat.setAttribute(newdatetimeIdx, 1.0)`